# Swing · Changing the JFrame's titlebar's icon's context menu's font

Tags: java, swing, jframe, contextmenu, titlebar

I want to know how to change the font of the text that appears in the context menu originated from right clicking at the icon that's all the way to the left in the titlebar of JFrames that use the default look and feel for decoration (`JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);`).

I searched around and found nothing. I thought that I could use what I learned about changing the font of the titlebar's title, but that didn't worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Thanks in advance."*  Err.. you're welcome.  But do you have a question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think that long first paragraph is supposed to be the question.

Comment: The frames border and icons are generally supplied by the OS, which takes out side of our control.  What look and feel are you using?  Nimbus or metal?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Metal, as I said "that use the default look and feel for decoration.", as in `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);`. As I also said, I did changed the title's font, so I can modify (at least some of) the decoration.

Comment: The default look and feel for Java 7 is Nimbus, hence the request for clarification

Comment: @MadProgrammer AFAIK, only if you use a GUI builder and let it do the work without supervision. If I do all by myself, the default has always been Metal, as of v1.7.0_25.

Comment: This is true, but the distinction makes a difference ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more messing around, I finally made it! I like Java so much that it makes me a bit sad how hard it is to do stuff like this. Anyway, I found a method [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/342116/GUI/java/set-font-JFileChooser) to recursively change the font of all components from a JFileChooser, but it doesn't work on the JPopupMenu (now I know the name) that pops up from the titlebar's icon. So I messed around with that method, used some casting, and was able to change the JMenuItems' font:

```
public static void setSubComponentFont (Component comp[], Font font) {
    for (int x = 0; x < comp.length; x++) {
        if (comp[x] instanceof Container) {
            setSubComponentFont(((Container)comp[x]).getComponents(), font);
        }  
        try {
            //comp[x].setFont(font);
            if (comp[x].toString().contains("JMenu")) {
                for (Component y : ((JMenu)comp[x]).getPopupMenu().getComponents()) {
                    if (y.toString().contains("JMenu")) {
                        y.setFont(font);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

I was inspired to use `.toString().contains()` by [this](https://forums.oracle.com/message/9221826) thread.

I also did this with nested loops, so the path to the menu items can be seen:

```
for (Component a : frame.getLayeredPane().getComponents()) {
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    if (a.toString().contains("MetalTitlePane")) {
        for (Component b : ((Container)a).getComponents()) {
            System.out.println(b.toString());
            if (b.toString().contains("SystemMenuBar")) {
                for (Component c : ((Container)b).getComponents()) {
                    System.out.println(c.toString());
                    for (Component d : ((JMenu)c).getPopupMenu().getComponents()) {
                        System.out.println(d.toString());
                        if (d.toString().contains("JMenu")) {
                            d.setFont(font);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every `System.out.println()` gives a hint to what should go on the following `if` condition, so they should be used one at a time. This doesn't work for the JFileChooser's title font though. When I have time I'll either look further into it or ask another question.

So, if someone else needs it like I did, here it is. As a tip, `System.out.println()` and `.toString()` are your friends! That's how I learned what was contained in each object, and what path I needed to take to get to the objects of interest.

Thanks anyway!